# Dashboard Bootstrap Components - Displaying Dropdown Menu based on viewport Size

Tags: css, callback, navbar, bootstrap-5, plotly-dash

As it stands, my navbar is composed as follows:

```
dbc.Navbar(
    dbc.Col(# logo is displayed here as div
        align="center",
        style={"display": "grid", "justify-content": "left"},
    ),
    dbc.Col(# app title is displayed here
        align="center",
        style={"display": "grid", "justify-content": "center"},
    ),
    dbc.NavbarToggler(id="navbar-toggler", n_clicks=0),
    dbc.Collapse(
        children=[right_elems],
        id="navbar-collapse",
        is_open=False,
        navbar = True
),
)
```

For reference, the Toggler only shows on specific Viewport sizes.

The children `right_elems` in the layout are defined with `style={"display": "grid", "justify-content": "right"}`. Which is perfect when the NavbarToggler doesn't show, but when it does, I am able to change their position to `center` when the Toggler is clicked.

I achieve it with this:

```
app.clientside_callback(
   '''
   function toggle_navbar(n, is_open){
       let items = document.getElementByClassName("menu-item");
       if (n){
           for (var i=0, i < items.length; i++){
                items[i].style.justifyContent = "center";
            }
           return !is_open;
       }
       for (var i=0, i < items.length; i++){
            items[i].style.justifyContent = "right";
       }
       return is_open;
   }
   '''
   Output("navar-collapse", "is_open")
   [Input("navbar-toggler", "n_clicks")],
   [State("navbar-collapse", "is_open")],
)
```

My problem now is that if the viewport is changed back to what is was without the Toggler showing, the `right_elems` stay with `justify-content: center` instead of going back to `justify-content: right`.

Is there a way to style the Menu items strictly when the menu is clicked and the `right_elems` show in said menu?